# How to solve `no live upstreams while connecting to upstream` when trying to rproxy jenkins using jwilder/nginx?

Tags: nginx, rproxy

https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

```
nginx.1    | 2018/03/04 22:24:54 [error] 102#102: *276 no live upstreams
while connecting to upstream, client: 83.85.143.226, server:
jenkins.releasesoftwaremoreoften.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream:
"http://jenkins.releasesoftwaremoreoften.com/", host: 
"jenkins.releasesoftwaremoreoften.com"
```

The docker-compose file looks as follows:

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=jenkins.releasesoftwaremoreoften.com
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8083
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8083:8080
      - 127.0.0.1:50000:50000
    volumes:
      - /usr/local/jenkins/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    networks:
      - rproxy
      - jenkins

networks:
  jenkins:
  rproxy:
    external:
      name: rproxy
```

Another attempt to make it work, was changing the VIRTUAL_HOST to 80, but that did not work as well.

Navigating to http://jenkins.releasesoftwaremoreoften.com/ returns a 502.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a spending a lot of time I decided not to continue with this approach and decided to use Jenkins helm.

Answer (score -1):

VIRTUAL_HOST is meant to point to the internal port, in your case it should be 8080 instead of 8083

Comment: Thank a lot. I spent a half of day with this problem. Its really not intuitive, that VIRTUAL_PORT should point to internal port.

Comment: btw, s/VIRTUAL_HOST/VIRTUAL_PORT/